# Xcode UI Test Crashes for exists, isHittable, waitForExistence and recording

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, uitest

I have a very simple Xcode UI Test with this function:

```
func waitForElementToAppear(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Bool {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        let exp = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
        let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [exp], timeout: 10)
        return result == .completed
}
```

Which has always worked for me before Xcode 9. I am not sure if this is an Xcode 10 issue, but it has recently started without me adding or changing any code.

Here is my test code:

```
func testTabBarPress() {
        let tabbar = self.app.tabBars["my_tabbar"]
        print(tabbar)
}
```

This test succeeds - always.

```
func testTabBarPress() {
    let tabbar = self.app.tabBars["my_tabbar"]
    print(tabbar)
    if tabbar.isHittable {  

    }
}
```

This test fails - always. It does not JUST fail, it crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

After more than 99.945 seconds it switches from crashed state to failed test state with the message: `Timeout waiting for fulfillment of promise for 'remote query'.`.

This test:

```
func testTabBarPress() {
    let tabbar = self.app.tabBars["my_tabbar"]
    print(tabbar)
    if waitForElementToAppear(tabbar) {

    }
}
```

Crashes with the same message of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but it does succeed afterwards.

I also did reset the simulators, cleaned the build folder and updated Xcode to 10.2.1 (10E1001)

At the top of my test I define my app:

`private var app: XCUIApplication = XCUIApplication()` and in `setup()` I launch it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the stack trace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000113a833d0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 80
    frame #1: 0x00000001322086f1 UIKit`-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveIvarText] + 364
    frame #2: 0x00000001321f5e54 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveTableViewIvarsText] + 118
    frame #3: 0x00000001321f6b27 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveTableViewCellText:] + 2749
    frame #4: 0x00000001321f99c1 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility accessibilityLabel] + 123
    frame #5: 0x000000012ee47739 PreferencesFramework`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility__Preferences__UIKit accessibilityLabel] + 327
    frame #6: 0x000000013243f31c UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityPotentiallyAttributedValueForNonAttributedSelector:attributedSelector:] + 244
    frame #7: 0x000000013243f478 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 41
    frame #8: 0x00000001321d620e UIKit`-[UINavigationBarAccessibility_UIViewAccessibilityAdditions _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 650
    frame #9: 0x000000013220b711 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement accessibilityLabel] + 48
    frame #10: 0x000000013243f31c UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityPotentiallyAttributedValueForNonAttributedSelector:attributedSelector:] + 244
    frame #11: 0x000000013243f478 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 41
    frame #12: 0x000000013243e9ae UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityProcessedLabelAttribute] + 34
    frame #13: 0x0000000132442c32 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] + 268
    frame #14: 0x000000013246cacd UIAccessibility`_accessibilityAttributesForObject + 493
    frame #15: 0x000000013246c43a UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotDescendantsWithAttributes:maxDepth:maxChildren:maxArrayCount:] + 1239
    frame #16: 0x000000013246dfd9 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotWithOptions:] + 1139
    frame #17: 0x0000000132441f09 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 8537
    frame #18: 0x00000001321cb100 UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 290
    frame #19: 0x0000000132424657 UIAccessibility`_copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 434
    frame #20: 0x0000000130ef1629 AXRuntime`___AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue_block_invoke + 50
    frame #21: 0x0000000130ef0f99 AXRuntime`_handleNonMainThreadCallback + 55
    frame #22: 0x0000000130ef14cb AXRuntime`_AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 285
    frame #23: 0x0000000130eec976 AXRuntime`AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 495
    frame #24: 0x0000000130e80351 XCTAutomationSupport`-[XCTAccessibilityFramework userTestingSnapshotForElement:options:error:] + 420
    frame #25: 0x0000000130e77e90 XCTAutomationSupport`-[XCTElementSnapshotRequest(PlatformImplementation) accessibilitySnapshotOrError:] + 1263
    frame #26: 0x0000000130e8305f XCTAutomationSupport`__56-[XCTElementSnapshotRequest loadSnapshotAndReturnError:]_block_invoke_2 + 64
    frame #27: 0x0000000130e728dd XCTAutomationSupport`__XCTPerformOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke + 295
    frame #28: 0x0000000111251aec CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #29: 0x00000001112512b0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    frame #30: 0x000000011124c10b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2747
    frame #31: 0x000000011124b302 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    frame #32: 0x000000011748d2fe GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #33: 0x0000000119ea2ba2 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
  * frame #34: 0x000000010d2afa4b Musify`main at AppDelegate.swift:20:7
    frame #35: 0x0000000113721541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #36: 0x0000000113721541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

And here is a trace for a recording crash:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000107c223d0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 80
    frame #1: 0x00000001269186f1 UIKit`-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveIvarText] + 364
    frame #2: 0x0000000126905e54 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveTableViewIvarsText] + 118
    frame #3: 0x0000000126906b27 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityRetrieveTableViewCellText:] + 2749
    frame #4: 0x00000001269099c1 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility accessibilityLabel] + 123
    frame #5: 0x0000000123633739 PreferencesFramework`-[UITableViewCellAccessibility__Preferences__UIKit accessibilityLabel] + 327
    frame #6: 0x0000000126b4f31c UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityPotentiallyAttributedValueForNonAttributedSelector:attributedSelector:] + 244
    frame #7: 0x0000000126b4f478 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 41
    frame #8: 0x00000001268e620e UIKit`-[UINavigationBarAccessibility_UIViewAccessibilityAdditions _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 650
    frame #9: 0x000000012691b711 UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement accessibilityLabel] + 48
    frame #10: 0x0000000126b4f31c UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityPotentiallyAttributedValueForNonAttributedSelector:attributedSelector:] + 244
    frame #11: 0x0000000126b4f478 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityAXAttributedLabel] + 41
    frame #12: 0x0000000126b4e9ae UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityProcessedLabelAttribute] + 34
    frame #13: 0x0000000126b52c32 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] + 268
    frame #14: 0x0000000126b7cacd UIAccessibility`_accessibilityAttributesForObject + 493
    frame #15: 0x0000000126b7c43a UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotDescendantsWithAttributes:maxDepth:maxChildren:maxArrayCount:] + 1239
    frame #16: 0x0000000126b7dfd9 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotWithOptions:] + 1139
    frame #17: 0x0000000126b51f09 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 8537
    frame #18: 0x00000001268db100 UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 290
    frame #19: 0x0000000126b34657 UIAccessibility`_copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 434
    frame #20: 0x00000001260bf629 AXRuntime`___AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue_block_invoke + 50
    frame #21: 0x00000001260bef99 AXRuntime`_handleNonMainThreadCallback + 55
    frame #22: 0x00000001260bf4cb AXRuntime`_AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 285
    frame #23: 0x00000001260b94f0 AXRuntime`_XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 414
    frame #24: 0x00000001260ce1b7 AXRuntime`mshMIGPerform + 237
    frame #25: 0x00000001053ea419 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    frame #26: 0x00000001053e9a7b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 459
    frame #27: 0x00000001053e400a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2490
    frame #28: 0x00000001053e3302 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    frame #29: 0x000000010b62c2fe GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #30: 0x000000010e822ba2 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
  * frame #31: 0x00000001013dea4b Musify`main at AppDelegate.swift:20:7
    frame #32: 0x00000001078c0541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #33: 0x00000001078c0541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

By the way, recording and tapping on elements also crashes.

EDIT 2:

I figured out that using the Accessibility Identifier the App also crashes.. So I just need to hover over the Simulator to make the app crash. I am out of ideas :(

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace where the crash occours and what pointer it tries to dereference?

Comment: appended stack trace, refresh :)

Comment: Is the test crashing? Or the app under test?

Comment: The App under the test crashes (at least it throws me into the app when crashing)

Comment: The app works fine tho, both in the simulator and on device and as soon as I add testing to it, it crashes

Comment: It seems I can trigger the crash with the accessibility inspector as well